# How do I calculate the average values in objects located in an array?

Tags: ruby, average

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "player_id"         => 1,
    "number_of_matches" => 2,
    "goals"             => 5
  },
  {
    "player_id"         => 2,
    "number_of_matches" => 4,
    "goals"             => 10
  }
]
```

I want to have the average goals per match among all the players, not the average for each individual player, but the total average.

I have in mind doing it with `.each` and storing each of the individual averages, and at the end add them all and divide by the number of players I have.  However, I am looking for a Ruby/ one-liner way of doing this.

Comment: You might want to fix your array/hash so that it's actually valid Ruby.

Comment: Sorry, I get a JSON and I map it to a hash. Let me edit that.

Comment: One-liners are interesting, but often overrated, IMO. I think asking for an *elegant* and *clean* solution is better than asking for a one-liner.

Comment: @Andrew: Agreed, especially because this doesn't seem to be a problem that can be solved elegantly in one libe.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall You are right. I will take that into account when formulating this kind of questions to avoid confusion in answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As requested, a one-liner:

```
avg = xs.map { |x| x["goals"].to_f / x["number_of_matches"] }.reduce(:+) / xs.size
```

A more readable snippet:

```
goals, matches = xs.map { |x| [x["goals"], x["number_of_matches"]] }.transpose 
avg = goals.reduce(:+).to_f / matches.reduce(:+) if goals
```

Comment: Kyle: Doing this in one line will require code repetition or inaccurate results.

Comment: Niklas: code repetition? Please explain how my solution is repeating code? It makes one pass over the array and produces the result.

Comment: @Kyle: I said *or inaccurate results*, like your solution, which sums up the individual division errors. If at all, you'd have to use `Rational`.

Comment: one-liner solution will lead to inaccurate result on big numbers, please look at my variant

Comment: @Kyle: Just replace every line break with a semicolon. Voilà: one-liner.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I answered with my one liner solution.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification to tokland's answer.

```
items.map{|e| e.values_at("goals", "number_of_matches")}.transpose.map{|e| e.inject(:+)}.instance_eval{|goals, matches| goals.to_f/matches}
```

Comment: Heh, nice trick with `instance_eval` :) I'd rather not see that in production code, though :P

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{player_id:1 , match_num:2, goals: 5}, {player_id:2 , match_num:4, goals: 10}]

a.reduce(0){|avg, p| avg += p[:goals].to_f/p[:match_num]}/a.size
```

**Edit:** renamed keys and block args to reduce char count. For those who care.

First, your keys need to use `=>` if your going to use strings as keys.

`reduce` will iterate over the array and sum the individual averages for each player and finally we divide that result by the number of total players. The '0' in the parenthesis is your starting number for `reduce`.

Comment: `arr.map { |p| p[:goals].to_f / p[:number_of_matches] }.reduce(:+) / arr.size` would be a bit shorter (and not overflow the code div).

Comment: Out of 93 characters in your one-liner, only 3 are spaces, and a few more around operators would make it far more readable.

Comment: Niklas: you are mapping and then reducing, thus iterating over the array twice when only one pass is required.

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, but a one-liner that does not fit the screen is not a one-liner. Usually code should wrap at about column 80. If performance were a concern, one would probably not choose Ruby for the job. Also, both solutions are `O(n)`, so it's not a "real" algorithmic difference.

Answer (score 0):

To make string shorter, lets rename `"number_of_matches"` to `"matches"`

```
a = [
  {"player_id":1 , "matches":2, "goals": 5}, 
  {"player_id":2 , "matches":4, "goals": 10}
]

a.reduce([0,0]){|sum,h|[sum.first+h["goals"],sum.last+h["matches"]]}.reduce{|sum,m|sum.to_f/m}
#=> 2.5
```